# Reproducing CMD Inside of an Image and something much faster than Console.Write

Tags: c#, image, performance, console

So, i have made an algorithm that converts normal images into objects that can be displayed in a 16-bit color console, like CMD. The rendering (converting a normal image to ones that i can display in the console) is easily paralellizable. The problem is displaying the image.

How i rendered a video :

- I converted the video's frames using the program (the conversion took 3-5 hours on 4 threads, and the result consisted in a folder with all the console-displayable frames.).
- To make the final frames, i had to display each frame in the console, than capture the window. But this took 13 hours, because Console.Write is VERY SLOW. Also, the resolution was low (only 200 characters in width), because any better than that would double the writing time.

I have tried accessing low-level stuff to make the colored Write faster, but to no end.

My question is : how would i go about completely reproducing the console visual style of the text and color from CMD within an image object in C# ? If i could just create an image and reproduce the console in it, i wouldn't have to write characters, capture the screen, crop it, and it would be almost instantaneous.
Alternatively, how could i make the colored Console.Write magnitudes faster?

Also, i have a way to directly edit the visual memory of a window, and i successfully played a video in real time inside the console window. What i am aiming for is the visual style that a console has. Generating an image instead of writing to the console could make it possible to render images of resolutions outside my screen size(because then the cmd would get out of bounds, even at the lowest font size). It would be much faster.

Link to the code : [GitHub](https://github.com/AntINFINAit/ConsoleImagery/blob/master/ConsoleImagery.cs)

Comment: Why not a windows form picturebox?

Comment: Give libcaca a look, I've seen some animation done with it, and I think there are c# bindings. (https://github.com/cacalabs/libcaca/tree/master/caca-sharp)